# Error when install the Composer LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could
>   not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.  in Unknown on line 0

Comment: install/enable php_pdo_firebird and php_imagick extensions for windows.

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't the right way to ask a question - you *explain* it, not dump a wall of text, and this sea of questionmarks... I mean really, is that the way we communicate in 2017.?

Comment: but i want solution not any kind of argument.

Comment: You were given the solution

Answer (score -2):

please check the php.ini file located in C:\xampp\php

and search extension=php_imagick.dll and replace with
 ;extension=php_imagick.dll

Comment: the line not existed